# Is there a Python equivalent of R's str(), returning only the structure of an object?

Tags: python

In Python, `help(functionName)` and `functionName?` return all documentation for a given function, which is often too much text on the command line. Is there a way to return only the input parameters?

R's `str()` does this, and I use it all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing in Python would probably be to create a function based off of [`inspect.getargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec), possibly via [`inspect.formatargspec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.formatargspec).

```
import inspect

def rstr(func):
    return inspect.formatargspec(*inspect.getargspec(func))
```

This gives you an output like this:

```
>>> def foo(a, b=1): pass
...
>>> rstr(foo)
'(a, b=1)'
```

Comment: This answers the question in the OP's post body, but not in the title. For most object types, this won't work.. Something like `{a: getattr(model, a) for a in dir(model) if not a.startswith('__')}` does work for most objects, but it's pretty unreadable, and not recursive like R's `str()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`inspect.getdoc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code).

Example:

```
>> print inspect.getdoc(list)
list() -> new empty list
list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```

And for methods of a class:

```
>> print inspect.getdoc(str.replace)
S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string

Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring  
old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Comment: `inspect.getdoc()` returns the same information as `help()`, which the OP already stated is sometimes too much.

Comment: @Amber: Oops, you are right. I got mislead because `help(list)` returns documentation for the whole class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 150 entries, 0 to 149
Data columns (total 4 columns):
sepal length (cm)    150 non-null float64
sepal width (cm)     150 non-null float64
petal length (cm)    150 non-null float64
petal width (cm)     150 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(4)
memory usage: 4.8 KB
```